# Tried making an if/else that involves a list

Tags: python

```
user_list=[177013,694205,452789]

def entry(usercode):
   global user_list
   if (usercode == user_list):
      print ("69")
   else:
      print ("no")
```

I just want to know how to use the list? Whenever I tried it, it only gave me the else's output i.e., "no" instead of the if's.

Comment: I would expect `entry([177013,694205,452789])` to work fine, assuming you fix the indentation. Please give a [mre] to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing everything under the `def` needs an extra indent. Also, do you want to find out if the `usercode` is in the `user_list`? If so, `if usercode in user_list:` should do it. No need for paranthesis.

Answer (score 0):

In the code block you provided, you're checking if the usercode you are getting is equals to the user_list. So if this is the correct scenario, the above code will give you **69** if the input is something like :

`usercode = [177013,694205,452789]`

Whereas if the scenario is that you need to check if usercode exists in the user_list then use `if usercode in user_list` instead of `if (usercode==user_list)`.